# Silverlight audio components

Tags: silverlight, components, libraries, audio

Do you know any good commertial or free audio / sound components that can be used in Silverlight (better on the client)?

Desired features:

- visualizing (waveform, peakform etc., zoom, editing volume, pan, start and end markers etc.)
- editing (channels: volume, pan, mute, fading, etc., merge, cut, copy, paste, etc.,   effects)
- mixing different sound tracks, creating a downmix
- exporting result in some in Silverlight usable (compressed) formats

Some useful projects that I've found:

- [Saluse MediaKit for Silverlight](http://salusemediakit.codeplex.com/)  (MP3 decoder, AudioPreProcessor, visualizers, effects)
- [Microsoft Design Toolbox sound mixer (incl. source code and video)](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/school/modules.aspx?lid=4&mid=11) and [Demo](http://archetype-inc.com/slminiapps/final/mixer/default.html)

Comment: Saluse is the best one I've seen so far. I plan to make a Silverlight version of NAudio as quite a few of the utlity classes it contains could be used in Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any tools or libraries that do exactly what you're looking for, but this Silverlight library might be able to help you understand how to implement those features. It is more meant to be used as a sound generator than for editing and mixing, but the principles of controlling volume, panning, and mixing are in the source code:

http://silversynth.codeplex.com/

The library only supports uncompressed, PCM wave audio.